# LINQ to SQL Efficiency

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am new to LINQ and I have a question regarding a "Hit the database once" type of transaction.

In the below code I am databinding the results of a query to a radio list.  I want to run the query once, then work with the results before databinding.  IE: If there are values, databind to the Radio list, otherwise show a textbox stating there are no values.

From my online searches I have only found that I can run the query once with a .count(), then run it again if the .count() is > 0.

I would prefer to hit the database once, then count the records, and proceed using the same resultset.

I was not sure of the terminology to use when searching, so please respond with the approprate terminology to use so that I can find the answer on my own!

```
using (RTOExceptionDataContext thisDataContext = new RTOExceptionDataContext())
{
    rdoSelectTransition.DataSource =    from tracking in thisDataContext.vw_RTOExceptionWorkflowTransitionMaps
                                                where tracking.RTOExceptionId.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RTOExceptionId"])) &&
                                                tracking.RTOSecurityLevel.Equals((int)Master.thisUserSecurityLevel)
                                                select new { tracking.RTOTransitionCd, tracking.TransitionDisp };
    rdoSelectTransition.DataTextField = "TransitionDisp";
    rdoSelectTransition.DataValueField = "RTOTransitionCd";
    rdoSelectTransition.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: use .ToList() and store result in a list. Then you can take count of list and use list values. How many items you are expecting in your result?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do this at all.  Just keep your binding code exactly as it is and use the `<EmptyDataTemplate>` within the markup of the `GridView` to indicate what should be shown in the event that you bind an empty collection to the `GridView`.

If you're binding data to a type of control that doesn't support a feature like this, then the easiest option is to simply eagerly materialize the query into a collection and then get the size of that in-memory collection.

```
var data = (from tracking in thisDataContext.vw_RTOExceptionWorkflowTransitionMaps
    where tracking.RTOExceptionId.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RTOExceptionId"])) &&
        tracking.RTOSecurityLevel.Equals((int)Master.thisUserSecurityLevel)
    select new { tracking.RTOTransitionCd, tracking.TransitionDisp })
    .ToList();

if(data.Any())
    //databind
else
   //do something else
```

Comment: I wasn't displaying the data in a gridview, it was a Radio Button List, which (per a quick google search, nothing exaustive) does not have an <emptyDataTemplate> option.  Your response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did find an answer to my question!  I am learning more about LINQ everyday, and I really love it!  This allowed me to databind if there are results.  Though the "else" is not shown below, it sets the visibility of the radio button to false.

```
        int thisUserSecurityLevel = (int)Master.thisUserSecurityLevel;
        int thisUserSelectedException = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RTOExceptionId"]);

        using (RTOExceptionDataContext thisDataContext = new RTOExceptionDataContext())
        {
            var query = from tracking in thisDataContext.vw_RTOExceptionWorkflowTransitionMaps
                        where tracking.RTOExceptionId.Equals(thisUserSelectedException) &&
                        tracking.RTOSecurityLevel.Equals(thisUserSecurityLevel)
                        select new { tracking.RTOTransitionCd, tracking.TransitionDisp };

            if (query.Count() > 0)
            {

                rdoSelectTransition.DataSource = query;
                rdoSelectTransition.DataTextField = "TransitionDisp";
                rdoSelectTransition.DataValueField = "RTOTransitionCd";
                rdoSelectTransition.DataBind();

            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is going to execute the query twice, not once, as is requested in the question.

Comment: And I was so excited!  I was trying to use .CopyToDataTable(), and the .ToList() as suggested by @Guanxi, but I was not able to perform a conversion to a datatable.  Back to the drawing board!

Comment: As an aside, you should use `query.Any()` instead of `query.Count()` because the `Count()` method must completely iterate through all of the results, while Any can stop iterating the instant it finds a single result.